# Сохранение обобщенной коллекции

Tags: c#, ооп

Имеются объекты:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}
```

Имеется класс сохранения этих объектов, а также их коллекции.

```
public class Repository
{
    public void Create(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
    {

    }

    public void Create(Cat cat)
    {

    }

    public void Create(Dog dog)
    {

    }
}
```

**ВОПРОС:** Можно ли реализовать метод `Create(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)` и обойтись без:

1. downcast
2. внедрения логики сохранения модели в саму модель

Если нельзя, то какой способ самый правильный или общепринятый? (вроде бы так ставить вопрос нельзя, но хотелось бы перенять опыт)

Решения, которые я придумал, но они не подходят под эти 2 пункта:

**1. DownCast**

Такая реализация нарушает принцип открытости-закрытости. Также DownCast сам по себе нарушает строгую типизацию.

```
public void Create(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        if (animal is Cat cat)
        {
            Create(cat);
        }

        if (animal is Dog dog)
        {
            Create(dog);
        }
    }
}
```

**1.1 DownCast v2**

Создать класс `Creator` и создать его наследников `CatCreator` и `DogCreator`.

Плюс: Уже вроде не нарушается закрытость-открытость, ведь нам не приходится вносить изменения в репозиторий. Просто нужно будет реализовать еще один `Creator`.

Минус: По прежнему есть DownCast, что не очень хорошо.

Мне этот способ кажется наименее неправильным.

```
public abstract class Creator
{
    public abstract bool CanCreate(Animal animal);
    public abstract void Create(Animal animal);
}

public class CatCreator : Creator
{
    public override bool CanCreate(Animal animal)
    {
        return animal is Cat;
    }

    public override void Create(Animal animal)
    {
    }
}

//Для DogCreator аналогично

public class Repository
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Creator> _creators;

    public Repository()
    {
        _creators = new List<Creator> // конечно надо DI, но для простоты сделал так
        {
            new CatCreator(),
            new DogCreator()
        };
    }

    public void Create(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
    {
        foreach (var animal in animals)
        {
            _creators.Single(creator => creator.CanCreate(animal)).Create(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

**2 перенести логику сохранения в класс `Animal`**

Избавляет от downcast, но тогда модель животного получает доступ к внешней системе, что тоже не хорошо.

```
public void Create(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        animal.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему методы `Create` возвращают `void`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Потому что их функция сохранить переданные объекты куда-то. Тоесть "Создать" их где-то. Я пытался писать в стиле CRUD.

Comment: Я бы назвал методы `Save` или `Write`. / Тут вопрос: сохраняем куда? Каким образом? В каком формате? / Можно заюзать рефлексию. Рефлектору пофиг, какой тип он получил на вход: рекурсивно пройдётся по всем свойствам и все примитивные типы запишет. / Можно взять готовый сериализатор (например, в JSON или MessagePack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, все объекты стоит сохранять в базу одинаково с помощью, например, сериализации.

Если нет, абстрагируясь от деталей сохранения объектов, по смыслу задачи подходит паттерн [Посетитель](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.11.php) (другое название – двойная диспетчеризация).

Пример реализации для вашего кода:

```
public interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(Dog dog);
    void Visit(Cat cat);
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    //...

    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
        => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    //...

    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
        => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public class Repository : IVisitor
{
    public void Create(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
    {
        foreach (var animal in animals)
            animal.Accept(this);
    }

    public void Create(Cat cat)
    {

    }

    public void Create(Dog dog)
    {

    }

    public void Visit(Dog dog) => Create(dog);

    public void Visit(Cat cat) => Create(cat);
}
```

Название методов `Visit` в интерфейсе можно заменить на `Create`, чтобы не дублировать методы в классе `Repository`.

Шаблон хорош тем, что с одной стороны вы соблюдаете все принципы ООП и SOLID, с другой стороны вам для этого нужно только единожды внести небольшие правки в классы-наследники `Animal` – а именно реализовать абстрактный метод `void Accept(IVisitor visitor)`, причем стандартной однострочной реализацией. После этого вы можете создавать любых "посетителей", реализуя интерфейс `IVisitor`, – например, менять репозитории на произвольные, либо вообще реализовывать произвольную логику для объектов `Animal` без внесения изменений в классы-наследники.

Comment: Спасибо за пример с посетителем. Я недостаточно подробно описал вопрос и сам не включил этот пример.  Он нарушает 2 условие вопроса "внедрения логики сохранения модели в саму модель". Да, фактически кода сохранения в модели нет, но модель обращается к логике сохранения (пусть и через интерфейс). Я исхожу из примерно той же логики, по которой, например, не следует добавлять интерфейес ILogger в модель (потому что логгер это внепроцессная зависимость). https://khorikov.org/posts/2021-05-17-domain-model-purity/

Comment: Идея с посетителем в том, что объект вашей модели выступает в роли некого "прокси" только лишь для диспетчеризации вызова метода и избавления от downcast-ов. Заметьте, объект вашей модели на самом деле не обращается к логике сохранения. Он вообще не знает, что для чего ему вызывать какой-то абстрактный `Visit()` самого себя. Более того, он и не должен никогда вызывать метод `Visit()` по собственной инициативе (из любого метода, отличного от `Accept()`. Связка Accept-Visit – это просто boilerplate для диспетчеризации вызова какого-то постороннего класса.

Comment: Да, технически, посетитель вероятно нарушает идею "domain model purity", описанную по вашей ссылке. Но, очевидно, только формально. В рамках таких ограничений, боюсь, не получится написать код без downcast-ов. Если бы ваши методы Create возвращали экземпляры объектной модели, а не принимали их в качестве параметров, можно было бы наплодить классов от какого-нибудь абстрактного `IAnimalCreator<out TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal` и обойтись ковариантностью интерфейса. Но у вас – контравариантность, а с ней апкастить конкретного Creator'а к IAnimalCreator не выйдет.

Comment: Да, тоже приходил к таким выводам. Думал что-то упускаю, но видимо действительно никак. Как вам кажется, чем лучше принебречь: "domain model purity" или строгой типизацией (использовать downcast)?

Comment: Downcast - это плохо примерно всегда :) Я не имел опыта разработки чистых моделей, но внедрение диспетчеризации выглядит вообще не криминально. Кстати, если погуглить "DDD and double dispatch", то оказывается, что это вообще дефолтная практика в DDD, но нужно детальнее изучить, что там в терминах "domain model purity" получается. И вот ещё ссылка, которая может быть полезной для вас: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502138/visitor-on-a-business-object-in-the-domain-in-hexagonal-onion-architecture

Comment: да, пожалуй, мне сразу надо было гуглить именно про шаблон постетителя в DDD) Видимо конечный ответ на мой вопрос такой: 1) соблюсти оба правила нельзя 2) лучше использовать посетителя